# Does a Facebook wrapper class written in PHP exist? like Twitter wrapper class written in PHP

Tags: class, facebook, twitter, wrapper

Where can i get a similiar http://code.google.com/p/php-twitter/ class for facebook?

The above class is very easy if i need to update my status on twitter i just do `$twitter->updatestatus("blabla");`
i need a similiar class for facebook where can i get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have seen this already, but facebook has a great PHP library for doing things just like that (and takes care of all the authentication stuff as well):

The code has been moved to https://github.com/facebook/platform/